# The word "attention" when referring to a package or letter

Tags: grammar

There's a package here to the attention of [name]

Or

We have received a letter to the attention of [name]

Are those statements grammatically correct?

Thank you

Comment: Would you be ok to post a little more detail and then format the question? I'm sure we would all like to see the context at work here so we can all enjoy it a little better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase needs to be 'for the attention of' (sometimes abbreviated [FAO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fao)). With that change to the preposition, either sentence would work, at least in the UK.

Comment: I've heard "to the attention of" in the US, and never "for the attention of."